# LINQ TO SQL Limited select statement because of group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am looking to find all the dealers in the database that have a duplicate phone number. I then want to list them in a report with all the dealers information.  I am having trouble getting my select statement to populate the dealer record attributes.

Such as dealer name address and so fourth. I am thinking it is because of the group by that is limiting it.

```
var dealers = _db.Dealers
            .Where(x => x.Active)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Phone)
            .Select(x => new { Dealer = x.Key, Phone = x.Count()})
            .Where(x => x.Phone > 1);
```

Edit: 
The desired output would be list of each dealer.  I want the dealers with the same phone number to appear next to each other.  I don't want any records that are not duplicates based on phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the first item in the group to the last Select:

```
var dealers = _db.Dealers
                 .Where(x => x.Active)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Phone)
                 .Select(x => new { Dealer = x.Key, Phone = x.Count(), FirstItem = x.First()})
                 .Where(x => x.Phone > 1);
```

the result will then have a `FirstItem` property

Or if you want *all* the items in a flat list you can apply the `Where` directly to the grouping:

```
var dealers = _db.Dealers
                 .Where(x => x.Active)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Phone)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
                 .SelectMany(g => g) // flat list of Dealers
```

Comment: @D Stanley I was displaying my data in mark up using `<%# Eval("Dealer")%>` etc. How can i make it so that when i am selecting i can target attributes of that record?

Comment: The second example should give you a flat list of `Dealer` objects so you should be able to access all of the properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying exactly what the expected output and the actual output is, so I don't know what you mean by 'having trouble'. But I spotted one potentially confusing thing:

You're grouping by the Phone (`.GroupBy(x => x.Phone)`).

So when you do `new { Dealer = x.Key, ...` the `x.Key` will refer to the phone number of this group.

Comment: I updated the questions the desired output you are right it was a little confusing.

Comment: @jackncoke ok based on your edit, the second example in D Stanley's answer seems correct.